# Where is my code for Overlaying transparent image over real image going wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to overlay a transparent image over my real image, so that if someone tries to right click on the image, he would download the transparent image, not the real one. 
I came across this following simple code upon googling and have been trying to tweak it to suit my blog's code. But haven't succeeded.

```
<div style="width:180px;height:186px;">
<img src="kids.jpg" width="180" height="186" alt="" style="z-index:0; position:absolute;" />
<img src="cover.gif" width="180" height="186" alt="My Kids"" style="z-index:1; position:absolute;" />
</div>
```

I created a transparent 1 x 1 pixel gif image and in the code, tried to make its size same as my real image. But for some reason, the transparent image gets placed just below my real image instead of overlaying on it, even if I have used z-indexes for them.
I guess I am going wrong with their positions (position absolute or position relative). Or am I going wrong somewhere else too?

This is the code I am trying:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"><tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;">
<a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJFva1CFgDQ/XMaJHwr_HfI/AAAAAAAADyA/OWPQ74ewwkkACWrByh-ALzin4_PQpfcYQCLcBGAs/s1600/Rice-Kheer-1.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; position: relative; z-index: 0;"><img alt="Rice Kheer" border="0" data-original-height="1000" data-original-width="1500" height="426" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJFva1CFgDQ/XMaJHwr_HfI/AAAAAAAADyA/OWPQ74ewwkkACWrByh-ALzin4_PQpfcYQCLcBGAs/s640/Rice-Kheer-1.jpg" title="Rice Kheer" width="640" /></a>
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xgpK1w1fuzg/XWNGJvO_wII/AAAAAAAAD0Y/k4o6yjDttBst_B73xjE6W8HcDmZmGOZigCLcBGAs/s1600/image.gif" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; position: relative; z-index: 1;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1000" data-original-width="1500" height="426" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xgpK1w1fuzg/XWNGJvO_wII/AAAAAAAAD0Y/k4o6yjDttBst_B73xjE6W8HcDmZmGOZigCLcBGAs/s1600/image.gif" width="640" /></a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">Odisha Special Rice Kheer</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: This is not going to prevent anyone from downloading the image though. If anything, such attempts just motivate people to download browser extensions that allows them to bypass such trickery.

Just let people download you images, they are already downloaded automatically to browser cache. Add watermarks to it (both visible and hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` to achieve this.

In addition to this, you can also add `oncontextmenu="return false"` to your tag which would prevent right click. These are some steps that you can take towards preventing using from downloading your images, but there isn't a full proof solution unfortunately.

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;position: relative;">
        <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJFva1CFgDQ/XMaJHwr_HfI/AAAAAAAADyA/OWPQ74ewwkkACWrByh-ALzin4_PQpfcYQCLcBGAs/s1600/Rice-Kheer-1.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="/* margin-left: auto; *//* margin-right: auto; *//* position: relative; *//* z-index: 0; */display: block;"><img alt="Rice Kheer" border="0" data-original-height="1000" data-original-width="1500" height="426" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NJFva1CFgDQ/XMaJHwr_HfI/AAAAAAAADyA/OWPQ74ewwkkACWrByh-ALzin4_PQpfcYQCLcBGAs/s640/Rice-Kheer-1.jpg" title="Rice Kheer"
            width="640"></a>
        <img border="0" data-original-height="1000" data-original-width="1500" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xgpK1w1fuzg/XWNGJvO_wII/AAAAAAAAD0Y/k4o6yjDttBst_B73xjE6W8HcDmZmGOZigCLcBGAs/s1600/image.gif" width="640" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">Odisha Special Rice Kheer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `#1` remove the `<br>` and `#2` remove height and padding css for the second image. Have edited the post.

Comment: I tried removing both the height css (height: 100%; height="426" but the issue persists.

Comment: you have not taken off `<br>`. this will solve the issue. I have update the post again to position the img directly, rather than having a `<a>` as wrapper.

Comment: actually I couldn't find the <br> tag. I just deleted the line break before "width="640"></a>" just after "title="Rice Kheer" of the 1st image. Anyway I have tried the updated code above and this time, the overlap is much better, although it is still overlapping.

Comment: The <br> tags are just not showing up on blogger's HTML code box as is seen in the imgur link that you shared. But anyway, I have now manually removed all the line breaks in the code on blogger and it is working now. Thank you so so much, Nidhin, thanks a ton, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: as mentioned in the above comment, you cannot 100% make sure that images cannot be downloaded, but you always can implement things like this. You can also add `oncontextmenu="return false"` to your `<tr>` tag which will even disable right click. just a FYI

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not a fool-proof method but at least it will deter some of those who are not that technically-oriented. I will surely try out the oncontextmenu too, thanks a lot for suggesting that. Thank you for all the help :)